# Changing VBA that creates Multiple PDFs to Single PDF

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

The code below is working great to create PDFs from Worksheet 3 to the Worksheet named "Post" while ignoring any hidden sheets.  It creates an individual PDF for each of these worksheets. This is linked to a shape that users click and are then prompted to select a folder to save all the PDFs.

**I'm trying to alter the code below to do the exact same thing EXCEPT create a single PDF with each visible worksheet between sheet 3 and "Post".**

I've been massaging the code around for a while and am wondering if anyone knows the best way to accomplish this?

```
Sub SaveAllPDF()
Dim i As Integer
Dim Fname As String
Dim TabCount As Long

TabCount = Sheets("Post").Index
'Set the TabCount to the last cell you want to PDF

Dim dialog As FileDialog
Dim path As String

Set dialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
dialog.AllowMultiSelect = False
If dialog.Show = -1 Then
    path = dialog.SelectedItems(1)
    ' Begin the loop.
    For i = 3 To TabCount
    'Set i = the number of the first sheet you want to PDF in order from left to right To TabCount
        If Sheets(i).Visible <> xlSheetVisible Then
        Else
            With Sheets(i)
                Fname = .Range("C15") & " " & .Range("E13") & "-" & .Range("B1")
                'The Fname above is equaling the cells that the PDF's filename will be
                'The folder directory below is where the PDF files will be saved
                .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:=path & "\" & Fname, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
            End With
        End If
    Next i

    Call Shell("explorer.exe" & " " & path & "\", vbNormalFocus)
    'This opens the folder where the PDFs are saved
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I did get this to work for now by hiding all Sheets by name if they're not between Sheet3 and Sheet "Post". Kind of a manual workaround as if there's a sheet in the future added that needs to be hidden outside of the Sheet 3 to "Post" then I'll have to go in and add code to hide. I'm still searching for an answer and will post solution if I find!

Answer (score 1):

If you select multiple worksheet tabs with the mouse, then select print, it will print them all as one print job, so give it a try in code:

```
Sub SaveAllPDF()
Dim i As Integer
Dim Fname As String
Dim TabCount As Long
Dim aSheetnames As Variant

TabCount = Sheets("Post").Index
'Set the TabCount to the last cell you want to PDF

Dim dialog As FileDialog
Dim path As String

Set dialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
dialog.AllowMultiSelect = False
If dialog.Show = -1 Then
    path = dialog.SelectedItems(1)
    ' Begin the loop.
    For i = 3 To TabCount
    'Set i = the number of the first sheet you want to PDF in order from left to right To TabCount
        If Sheets(i).Visible <> xlSheetVisible Then
        Else
            redim preserve aSheetnames(i-2)  'subtract 2, since i starts at 3
            asheetnames(i-2) = sheets(i).name  'build array of the sheets to print
        End If
     Next
     Fname = 'make something up here for your bulk file name
     Sheets(asheetnames).ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:=path & "\" & Fname, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

End If
End Sub
```

**NOTE**: No guarantees expressed or implied, you may have to do some debugging, as this is off the top of my head, but it just might work...

Comment: Playing around with this idea. Although, I don't think I want to subtract to from i as I'm trying to capture Sheet 3 to "Post". Thanks for response, I'll play around with this idea and see if I can get it to work

Comment: @user3026842 the `aSheetnames()` array starts at 1, while `i` starts at 3. If you don't subtract 2 from it, you'll end up with 2 empty spots in the array, and I'm not sure what that would do to the `.ExportAsFixedFormat`. But, as I said, untested code to push you in a possibly right direction, so see where it gets you.

Comment: Ah gotcha, thanks for explanation. I'm in the very early stages of VBA learning. I think this will work, I'll letcha know

Answer (score 1):

This works in my file for emailing visible tabs as pdf's your use while different the same applies...you don't need to code for hidden/not hidden with this

```
' Export activesheet as PDF
 With ActiveWorkbook
      .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=PdfFile,  
              Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True,     
                     IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
 End With
```

Comment: Thanks for response! Looking into how I can make sure all sheets outside of Sheet 3 to "Post" are hidden while keeping the sheets between Sheet 3 to "Post" unaffected and then applying the regular export as PDF code you mentioned. I'll post if I can get it to work

Answer (score 0):

Instead of exporting each worksheet **inside** the loop, export the entire workbook **outside** the loop with [Workbook.ExportAsFixedFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198122.aspx).

With this method, arguments `From` and `To` allow you to select what pages to output. However, you need to know where the visible worksheets page numbers lie. It may not necessarily be per their worksheet number as some worksheets can print into multiple pages. Find page numbers by manually saving entire workbook in PDF.

Alternatively, you can continue with your loop and combine multiple PDFs using the [Adobe Acrobat SDK](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/iac_api_reference.pdf). See `AcroExch.AvDoc` and `AcroExch.PDDoc` objects. However, users of your Excel workbook will need to have Adobe Acrobat (not just the free Reader) installed on their machines to reference the Adobe API in VBA.

Comment: Thanks for response. Unfortunately, Acrobat can't be assumed to be on each machine and I have no control over that. There's a changing # of sheets outside of Worksheet 3 to "Post" that can't be included in this PDF so Exporting the entire Workbook won't be an option. Although that did spark an idea to maybe try and hide all sheets outside of Worksheet 3 to "Post" (i.e. hide sheet 1, 2, 16 and on). "Post" is Sheet 14.